# Selecting the left part of an array built from push.apply([user.email, user.groupName])

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, ecmascript-5

I have a section of code that extracts a list of users from a Google group, it looks at a 'top level' group, then extracts the user email and the group they are in. In the case of nested groups, it traverses and does the same again. So the output is essentially this:

```
| User (Column A)       | Group (Column B)      |
|---------------------- |-------------------    |
| userFoo@email.com     | Top Level Group       |
| userBar@email.com     | Top Level Group       |
| userQux@email.com     | Top Level Group       |
| userQuux@email.com    | Sub Level Group 1     |
| userCorge@email.com   | Sub Level Group 2     |
| userUier@email.com    | Sub Level Group 2     |
| userGrault@email.com  | Sub Level Group 3     |
| userGarply@email.com  | Sub Level Group 3     |
| userWaldo@email.com   | Sub Level Group 3     |
```

Where there are only 3 people in the top level group, and 3 sub groups within it (with 1, 2 and 3 members respectively).

This is stored within an array called output, which is built by using AdminDirectory.Group.get and pushing the primaryEmail and the groupName to the array:
`output.push.apply([user.email, user.groupName])`
This is later dumped into a sheet.
What I am wanting to take the user.email section from the output array, and create a unique list from it. I have a function to generate a unique list:

```
function uniqueList(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
```

So I just need a hand with creating a 'clean' list (meaning without the Group name info) from output. Granted, I could just create another array and push only the user.email part to that, but it feels uncessesary as I've already got that information.

Main code:

```
function extract() {
  var masterSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(
    "idGoesHere"
  );

  var inputSheet = masterSS.getSheetByName("Input");
  var topGroup = inputSheet.getRange("B1").getDisplayValue();
  var outputSheet = masterSS.getSheetByName("Output");
  var uniqueOutput = masterSS.getSheetByName("Unique List");

  if (topGroup.length != 0) {
    Logger.log(topGroup);
  } else {
    throw "No Group Found!";
  }

  try {
    var users = getUsersInGroup_(topGroup);
    var output = [];
            // Create the list of users + groups
    users.forEach(function(user) {
      output.push.apply([user.email, user.groupName]);
    });

    if (!outputSheet) {
      masterSS.insertSheet("Output");
    }
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();

    masterSS
      .getSheetByName("Output")
      .getRange(1, 1, output.length, output[0].length)
      .setValues(output);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    spreadsheetCleanUp_;
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e);
  }
}
```

I'm sure this is simple, but I've hit a blank. Clearly, I need more coffee.

Comment: Why don't you push the emails to a separate array at the same time as you're pushing to the output? Initialise another array (`emailArr` for example) under the `var output = [];` line and use `emailArr.push(user.email);` inside of your `users.forEach` function? I assume that's not what you mean by 'I could just create another array [from the output array?]'.

Comment: That's the quick easy fix (it's what I'm doing at the moment), but it feels wasteful/inefficient as I already have the data there.

Comment: Show the `output` array.  I'm fairly sure `output.push.apply([user.email, user.groupName]);` doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: If you're accessing the emails one at a time in a loop, you could use `output[i][0]` to access the first column.

Comment: Also note that your unique list is terribly slow - consider using an object mapping. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50286994/9337071 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/49519839/9337071

Comment: @TheMaster sorry, that should be push([stuff]) not push.apply. You're right.

Comment: @tehhowch I'm game for learning anything that will speed things up! I will take a look, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functional approach to selecting a portion of a native `Array` is to use `Array#map` and return the desired index:

```
var users = ...;
var emails = users.map(function (user) { return user[0]; });
```

If you need the current user emails from the list of objects in several different places, and you modify the source list in between, you might abstract this to a helper:

```
function getIndex_(userObjs, index) {
  return index < 0 ? [] : userObjs.map(function (user) { return user[index]; });
}
```

Usage would then be similar to:

```
var names = getIndex_(users, headers.indexOf("name"));
```

where `headers` is something like `["name", "email", "lastLogin", ...]` and was used to create the `users` object.

Comment: Hey tehhowch,  thanks for the answer. I've now managed to solve my problem and will be looking into maps in more details, seems super handy. Hope you had a great Christmas!

Answer (score 1):

A quick and easy solution is to add another column in the sheet with a UNIQUE formula that references the user column.